# boot filename not found with windows 7 ultimate+ recently upgraded ubuntu14.4 LTS dual boot+strange ticking sound

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, data-recovery, user-data

I had windows 7 and ubuntu 12.4 LTS installed for months.. have important data in both sections especially under root account of ubuntu...  and D and G drives in windows partition.. not much in the host partition of windows.

Recently found a .Trash hidden folder under G drive. Read that it is not a virus.. came from saving files from ubuntu in newvolumeG.

Was going smoothly except for a few unity issues. Which i was slowly learning to get rid of.. to get my convenient desktop back. Had swap partitions with missing UUID.. 
dev/mapper/cryptswap not found error was there.. 
.bashrc file showed a filename instead of a uuid of the sda6 or 8. There were two swap partitions.. one with 2 gb another with 5 gb. None were used after the error started to show up as i guess after i checked disk-utility.

A few days ago i unpluged LAN cable. Was doing some offlne reading of offline saved web pages on unity issues. Net was not needed. And i sometimes do. 
Within 24 hrs a strange ticking sound started like when a cd gets stuck.
I got afraid and closed the lid. Did not open the lappy for two days.
Now when i attempt to start in place of grub being loaded with list of partitions to boot into it gives me this on a blank screen. 
atheros PCIE ETHERNET CONTROLLER 
CLIENT MAC: 6 SEGMENT HEX
GUID ... some more hex...
PXE-E53 : NO BOOT FILENAME RECEIVED
PXE-M0F: EXITING INTEL PXE ROM

That strange sound is still coming possibly from HDD.
My lappy is a Toshiba satellite c665 pc
Cd drive not working.
USB working.
Need to save and access all data under root and windows D and G drive.

Answer (score 1):

That message you're getting is the network boot option that most BIOSes have. It's usually the last entry in the boot order, so it means your hard drive isn't being seen. The clicking sound and this boot problem lead me to believe that your hard drive is dead. You're almost definitely going to have to take it in to have the drive cloned or the data taken off. If you have another computer though, you might be able to make an Ubuntu LiveUSB, boot from that and then copy your important files to another USB drive, before buying a new hard drive and reinstalling Windows and Ubuntu. I recommend the professional drive transfer, though.

Comment: Zacharee1, can u tell me what caused this death of my HDD?

Comment: Also would need to know if i will be able to access.. edit the folders and files created under root if can get a backup of all the drives.. i mean manual copy is possible? From another computer?

Comment: Well, it sounds like your hard drive has failed: it's broken. You either need to get it repaired or cloned and replaced. It is possible, but highly improbable, that you can use a LiveUSB to copy the files to another drive.

Comment: Any idea why this could happen? I mean ubuntu is one of the best OS.. in terms of security nd protection.... !!! What exactly did i do wrong? It can happen again? Any possible precaution?

Comment: @ananyaaaniya there's nothing you could have done. When hard drives get old they wear out and can just break down. It has nothing to do with what OS you run. It's based mostly on how old the hard drive is, how good the hard drive is and how many files are transfered in its lifetime.

Comment: It was seagate 500 gb... only abt 1.5 yrs old... Too bad. Ya i hv created and transferred lots of files from this location to that... within the drive... could switching between windows and ubuntu be a problem? Accessing or transferring too many files from ubuntu partition to windows? Does this mean that a HDD must have one single OS?

Comment: No it doesn't. Don't worry. Just get a new drive, transfer what you need, and you'll be fine. I'd recommend a 1TB drive. You can get laptop versions for about $60USD on Amazon.

Comment: I need to wait a few days until these all are done... please dn't mind.

Comment: The disk probably wd not be gone if i could detect the tick as early as possible and wd shut down the laptop properly with proper battery life. No? And if i could contact a hardware recovery company who carefully replaces the platter in the ideal environment in some ideal machinery and the right circuit board. Trying repeatedly switch on or off has made the scratch and my craziness has jeopardised the controller i suppose. I will not leave it. Just moving aside. I donot leave what i love most.

Answer (score 1):

I think i have guessed the reason now. Last night i opened my valuable harddisk filled with memories of people i may never meet again.. the last voices.. the first interactions... expressions... copies of important documents.. programs.. and plans... etc. But they are best left inside my mind.
May be i was mad too and went crazily daring. Took as much precaution as i could.. created a stand to safely keep the HDD.

The inside was filled with tiny small black remnants. The coarsed thin rubber sides was clearly visible. The head was aside... not on the disk. And it could not go radially inward beyond a certain radius.. as i very very gently tried to slide it over the disk. There was initially no line of scratch on the disk but my trial did leave a tiny mark. Ya... I ruined it further.

The rubber may got coarsed from extreme heat to hv undergone continuous power flow for more than 24 hrs.. quite reoeatedly over tge last few months.
Or ants got inside through spaces.. ya am having a breakout of very small red ants in my place. And choaked the movement of head and died. Do not hv enough knowledge or set up to test the residue. May be a rubber solvent or protein solvent could tell me. But i had none.

So i focussed cleaning up by blowing air as carefully as possible.. not touching anything.. and set everything back to turn it on to see if the ticking persists.. ya. It persisted. The head was not able to move inner most region.

Only possibility is that the spindle got higher enough before i closed the lid on thursday. And it got stopped right then as the power was off... i had no battery charge left in the lappy. And may be it expects the head to be at default reading position at the beginning of each start up. Do not know the rest. I opened it up and now saw a ring of scratch near the inner rim. I rotated the spindle following the thumb rule to try it last time to get it in the reading sector.. i could not.. as i suppose .. match the rpm of 5400. Even trying for hours.
So bottomline.. i ruined everything.. may be all data is lost forever... nothing to do apart from using live usb stick. And it is serving me well for now.

Hope this information helps you. But i wd say go to extreme to know it. Do Explicitly All for what you love and care. Human beings and memories of them are worth any possible disaster that may come in the way.. break the norms.

Though i feel sort of numb.. but i think they wd cradle me with love being there by my side for whom i just could not leave it on some strangers and did all i could at the moment... 
Or should i just hv waited?? In patience? 
Both feels correct.